# Git subtree pull deletes the files in my top-level repository

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a Git repository with a subtree.  I added the subtree about a month ago, and it didn't give me any problems at the time.  Now, however, I've made a change to the subtree repo, and I need to bring those changes into my project.  When I try to pull the subtree, however, instead of updating the subtree files, it overwrites my top-level project repo with the files from the subtree.

Here's the command I'm using:

```
 git subtree pull --prefix=Dependencies/RDLC subRDLC master --squash
```

subRDLC is the remote connection to the subtree repo.

I've used and updated subtrees in other projects and never run into this problem before.  Is there an additional flag I should be using, or is the syntax totally wrong.  I'm using Git version 2.25.1.windows.1.

Thank you.